# Sed find and replace Cpp file(.C)

Tags: sed

I am having issues of editing huge `C++` file where I am using `sed` to convert `List(something)` to `List<something>` why I am doing this because our List has been converted to template.

Command I have written in small shell file is like this

```
sed -i '/List/s/(/</g' $1 
sed -i '/List/s/)/>/g' $1
```

But this command is converting the whole line associated with List to angular braces like,

`some_Fun(List(something))` to `some_Fun<List<something>>`

I don't want `sed` to change `some_Fun<>` , `sed` should keep `some_Fun()` and change only `List()` to `List<>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(List\)(\([^)]*\))/\1<\2>/g' file
```

(OR)

```
sed 's/List(\([^)]*\))/List<\1>/g' file
```

Comment: probably add that this will also change `List()` to `List<>` .. if that is not desirable, use `\+` instead of `*`

Comment: This is changing funcList() to funcList<> it has to convert only List not the Listkeyword associated all function names.

Comment: Thank you everyone this is my task now.I will work on it.